# When trying to install the alsa-base package on linux, ask to uninstall linux-headers on debian, how can I solve this?

Tags: linux, operating-system, debian

I am a beginner in linux, I installed several packages on my system that are causing conflicts, one of which is alsa base, which always asks to remove linux headers from the kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed some "packages" kernels set unusable, you can first issue the following commands:

**1#** check - Verify that there are no broken dependencies

```
$ sudo apt-get check
```

**2#** autoremove - Remove automatically all unused packages

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

- If the above info did not work; we can check if you have installed the proper kernel on Debian, so  check out your current kernel by

  $ uname -sr

Then you can uninstall those unused kernal-headers by:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-xxxx
```

reemplace the "xxxx" by the kernel you want delete.

I recommend you also take a look at this 
[link](https://www.tecmint.com/remove-old-kernel-in-debian-and-ubuntu/) where talks more over about; and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253048/safe-to-remove-usr-src-linux-headers-after-purging-older-linux-images) a troubleshooting done by a user wanted to delete header-kernel in askubuntu.